# click anywhere except a specified class

Tags: javascript, jquery

I need to show an alert if there is a click anywhere except on `.m1wrap` div.

Why this doesn't work? Alert appears even if I click on `.m1wrap`

```
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.class !== "m1wrap") {
        alert ("323");
    };
})
```

Comment: `if (!$(e.target).hasClass('m1wrap')`

Comment: @Tushar, what if exceptions divs are `.m1wrap` and all its children`, pls ?

Comment: Elements can have multiple classes

Comment: @Tushar Correct me if I'm woring. This  would work for the children elements too. So don't worry about it.

Comment: @bonaca You can use `$(e.target).is('.m1wrap')`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In `e.target` there is no property `class` (it returns `undefined`), you can  use property `e.target.className` (Note it returns all classes from `class` attribute), however in `jQuery` there is method [`.hasClass`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) .

Also you can use [`classList`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/classList) with `.contains` method `e.target.classList.contains('m1wrap')`

```js
$(document).on('click', function (e) {
  if (!$(e.target).hasClass('m1wrap')) {
    console.log('not m1wrap');
  }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m1wrap">m1wrap</div>
<p>test</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) to address the `class` attribute.

So either use jQuery's [`hasClass()`](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) or vanilla JS [`className`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className).

Note: This example using `className` is only checking if the class does not *equal* "m1wrap", rather than does not *contain* "m1wrap".

```js
$(document).on("click", function(e) {
    if (e.target.className !== "m1wrap") {
        alert ("323");
    };
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="m0wrap">m0wrap</div>
<div class="m1wrap">m1wrap</div>
<div class="m2wrap">m2wrap</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

There is no `class` in `e.target`, only `className` is available.

**Code snippets:**

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (e.target.className !== "m1wrap") {
        alert("323");
    };
})
```

But the following code snippets is the best way if there is multiple class names for an element.

```
$(document).on("click", function (e) {
    if (!$(e.target).hasClass('m1wrap')) {
        alert("323");
    };
})
```

Answer (score 1):

[Event.target](https://api.jquery.com/event.target/) returns [Element](http://api.jquery.com/Types/#Element), which has not **class** property.

So you can use **className** property or **getAttribute()** method to get Element's class name.

If you want to use jQuery API, you can use [hasClass()](https://api.jquery.com/hasclass/) method

Answer (score 0):

Try this,

```
<div>
    <div class="m1wrap">
        Non Clickable area
    </div>
    Clickable area
    Clickable area
    Clickable areaClickable areaClickable
    Clickable areaClickable
    Clickable area
</div>
```

JS

```
$(('body')).on('click',function(e) {
 if ($(e.target).hasClass('m1wrap')) {
        return false;
    }
  alert("hello");
})
```

[***DEMO***](http://jsfiddle.net/bemv1frb/2/)